# How to get the dynamic stack view height in Swift

Tags: swift, uistackview

I have a stackView in my project. There are 6 elements in the stackView which have different values for height. And a fix spacing value for the stackView and some of them have top constraint. Is it possible to calculate the whole stackView height?

```
stack view
   line 1    H = 20   spacing from top = 0
   line 2    H = 15   spacing from top = 10
   line 3    H = 30   spacing from top = 0
   line 4    H = 10   spacing from top = 0
   line 5    H = 10   spacing from top = 15
   line 6    H = 15   spacing from top = 0

stack view spacing = 10
```

I want to calculate the whole stackView height programatically.

Comment: `stackView.frame.height`? It autosizes...

Comment: On a side note it appears to be a vertical stack view. The spacings from top will cause ambiguous/conflicting constraints.